# Insert javascript into javascript html return

Tags: javascript, html

I've got an HTML table that's being returned using javascript `return` function. It works perfectly until I try to add an additional `if` clause into the middle of it.

```
function format ( d ) {
    return '<div class="slider">'+     
    '<table id="expand">'+
        '<tr>'+
          '<td><button class="btn btn-success" value="Save" onclick="saveItem(this)" data-soli="'+d.soli+'" data-comments="'+d.comments+'" >Save</button></td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td class="dropHeader">Customer</td>'+
            '<td class="black">'+d.customer+'</td>'+
            '<td class="dropHeader">Value</td>'+

            if (d.country !== "usd") {
              '<td class="red">'+d.value+'</td>'+
            } else {
              '<td class="black">'+d.value+'</td>'+
            }                

            '<td class="dropHeader">Comments</td>'+
            '<td class="black"><input onblur="submitComments(this.value)" type="text"><br>'+d.comments+'</input></td>'+            
        '</tr>'+                                               
    '</table>'+    
   '</div>'; 
}
```

The code is failing when I add the `if` clause.  Is this a syntax issue?  How do I go about breaking the HTML for a second so I can add additional javascript into the return?  My goal in this is to add the td class `red` whenever the line's currency is in USD, but I can't figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: bad syntax. You cant add code inside a string like that

Comment: @CodeGodie Yeah, I figured my `Is this a syntax issue?` statement kind of covered the fact that I understood that already......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way

```
function format ( d ) {
var cssClass="";
if (d.country !== "usd") {
cssClass="red";
}
else{
cssClass="black";
}
    return '<div class="slider">'+     
    '<table id="expand">'+
        '<tr>'+
          '<td><button class="btn btn-success" value="Save" onclick="saveItem(this)" data-soli="'+d.soli+'" data-comments="'+d.comments+'" >Save</button></td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td class="dropHeader">Customer</td>'+
            '<td class="black">'+d.customer+'</td>'+
            '<td class="dropHeader">Value</td>'+
            '<td class="'+cssClass+'">'+d.value+'</td>'+           
            '<td class="dropHeader">Comments</td>'+
            '<td class="black"><input onblur="submitComments(this.value)" type="text"><br>'+d.comments+'</input></td>'+            
        '</tr>'+                                               
    '</table>'+    
   '</div>'; 
}
```

Comment: all of these responses are great as a learning experience, but this one is the one I'm gonna go with.  It allows me to keep my code the same after the `return`, but just insert variables prior to that and use them.  Thank you so much!  Seems like such a simple oversight on my behalf :)

Answer (score 5):

Using [Ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx), eg:

```
... etc ...
+
'<td class="dropHeader">Value</td>'
+
(d.country !== "usd" ? '<td class="red">'+d.value+'</td>' : '<td class="black">'+d.value+'</td>')
+
'<td class="dropHeader">Comments</td>'
+
... etc ...
```

Comment: This is really great as well!  I didn't realize I could do this.  I'm gonna read up on ternary operators as well.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnWu then this is not the correct mark answer? :(

Comment: well I can only mark one as the correct answer.  They're all correct, so I marked one and gave the rest of you fake internet points.  I chose the other answer because it's the solution I ended up going with.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is because, in essence, you're doing the equivalent of:

```
return "Something" + if(condition){}else{} + " else";
```

Which is illegal syntax for Javascript.

There are two solutions to this; the first is to use the inline if statement, as such:

```
return "Something" + (x == y ? "output if succeeded" : "output if not") + ".";
```

So your inline if would turn into:

```
+ (d.country !== "usd" ? '<td class="red">'+d.value+'</td>' : '<td class="black">'+d.value+'</td>') +
```

Or for a second solution, you could have an output string that you append things to, as so:

```
function format(d){
    var output = "";

    output += "Testing code";

    if(d.country !== "usd"){
        output += "Woo we succeeded";
    }

    output += " more testing <i>code<i>.";

    return output;
}
```

Comment: yeah this is wonderful as well! Thank you for taking the time to write this - it's taught me a lot about different approaches I can take to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
        if (d.country !== "usd") {
          '<td class="red">'+d.value+'</td>'+
        } else {
          '<td class="black">'+d.value+'</td>'+
        }
```

To this:

```
+((d.country !== "usd")?'<td class="red">'+d.value+'</td>':'<td class="black">'+d.value+'</td>')+
```